# Exiting python Pipe and setting var

Tags: python, function, debugging, popen

I am using the following metohd to read the output of my python script concurrently and write it to a file:

```
FoundError = 0    
def execute(command):    
  with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='',flush=True)
        if 'Error found in job. Going to next' in line:
            FoundError = 1
            break
execute(myCmd)
print(FoundError) --->>this gives a 0 even if I see an error
```

I want to check the output for a string and set a variable if I see a particular error string. Upon an error, I set a variable to be used later, but this variable looses its value. I want to use this value in the further part of my code.
Why is the variable loosing its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FoundError` inside the function is a local variable that has nothing to do with `FoundError` from the outer scope.

Return the flag from the function instead:

```
def find_error(command):
    ...
    if 'Error found in job. Going to next' in line:
        return True # found error

found_error = find_error(command)
print(found_error)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, I was afraid of trying a return as I did not want to mess the buffered prints.

Comment: This is your code from another question. Thanks for all the help :)